# WMI Query to count number of messages in MSMQ poison queue

Tags: vbscript, wmi, msmq

I can query the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue` WMI object to get the count of messages on an MSMQ queue as below, however this will return a cumulative count of messages on the queue and it's subqueues (e.g. poison and retry). Ideally I would like to get a count of messages on the poison queue alone.

Is this possible using WMI?

```
Dim Locator
Set Locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Dim objs
Set Service = Locator.ConnectServer(".", "root\cimv2")
Set objs = Service.ExecQuery("SELECT MessagesinQueue " &_
                 "FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue " &_ 
                 "WHERE Name LIKE '%\\private$\\myqueue'")

For Each object In objs
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & object.Name
    WScript.Echo "MessageCount: " & object.MessagesInQueue
Next
```

Given the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on subqueues the result above makes sense as subqueues are just a logical partition of the main physical queue, but is there any other WMI object or attribute I can query to identify poison messages?

Comment: The poison queue doesn't exist as a distinct queue and so doesn't have it's own performance object counter instance. It's just a partition of the "real" queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use "SELECT MessagesinJournalQueue " if you like to query the journal messages.
The journal queue is not a separate queue.